# How much does a referee/umpire earn in a year?

Tags: officiating, international-sports, finances

Is it possible to create an approximate draw with the earning of the referee in the most important sports(Soccer/Basketball/Volleyball/Tennis/Cricket etc.)?

Comment: I know that in soccer some of the refs have a full time job alongside their career as a referee so I can't imagine they earn a lot unless there is a big difference between what top refs make in comparison to middle of the road refs

Comment: @RoB The referee appointed for the Champions League final has a job alongside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referees and umpires get paid much differently depending on the sport.

For the first example, let's take the most watched sport in the world: football (known to Americans as soccer). European soccer referees [get paid](http://www.tsmplug.com/football/average-salary-premier-league-referees/), on average, about the equivalent of $120,000 a year (salary plus match fees). Of course, this depends on the quality of the referee, but it is quite apparent that this is nothing compared to soccer players (about a two weeks salary in average).

For the most watched sport in the United States, American football, referees get paid much higher. For the 2013-2014 season, NFL referees [got paid](http://www.celebritynetworth.com/articles/how-much-does/nfl-referee-salary/) on average $173,000 (an increase from $149,000 the preceding year). Of course, rookie (first year) referees make much less, and verteran referees can make up to $200,000 per season.

In tennis, the idea is different. Umpires get paid by the match, since every tournament has a different level of importance (Grand Slams being the most important). The salaries also differ depending on the tournament. For the sake of simplicity, let's [compare](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/07/sports/tennis/many-top-tennis-umpires-skip-the-us-open.html) the salaries of "Gold Badge Umpires" (the highest position for a tennis umpire), from the four grand slams.  A spreadsheet obtained by The New York Times showed that Wimbledon paid gold badge umpires £189, or about $306 daily. The French Open paid 190 euros (about $270), even for the tournament’s qualifying rounds, while the United States Open pays $185 a day for its qualifying rounds.

At the Australian Open, gold badge umpires earn about $383 for each main draw day, and they make overtime if they work more than 10 hours, a perk none of the other Grand Slam tournaments provide.

Cricket umpires can make anything from $30,000 to $45,000 in [annual salary](http://www.tsmplug.com/cricket/icc-elite-panel-umpires-salaries/). This is just the salary. Depending on the match, either a ODI (one day international) or a test match (which last considerably longer than ODI's), they also gain match day fees. For a test match, the fee is usually around $3,000 while a ODI can pay around $800-$1,000.

Answer (score 3):

[Goal.com](http://www.goal.com/en-us/news/1786/fifa/2011/03/04/2379063/revealed-how-much-referees-are-paid-in-each-european-country) had a table on how much refs get paid in the top leagues in Europe from around 2011.
How Much Officials Earn Per Domestic League Game (€)

England   1,170* (Referee)    375 (Referee Assistant)

Spain     6,000 (Referee)     2,000 (Referee Assistant)

Germany   3,600  (Referee)    1,800 (Referee Assistant)

Italy     3,400   (Referee)   1,700 (Referee Assistant)

France    2,751  (Referee)    -

Portugal  1,188 (Referee)     594 (Referee Assistant)

*EPL referees are paid a retainer of €38,500 per season which explains why their fee per game is lower than some of the other leagues.

On average top tennis umpires can expect to earn £50-£60,000 per annum, but it takes a long time to get there! Most earn around £30,000. On average a line judge can expect to earn £20,000 ([BBC Sport](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/tennis/get_involved/4541821.stm)).

In [cricket](http://www.tsmplug.com/cricket/icc-elite-panel-umpires-salaries/);

ELITE PANEL OF ICC UMPIRES

1   Aleem Dar (Umpire)         $45,000  (Basic Yearly Salary)           $3,000  (Test Match Fee)    $850 (ODI Match Fee)

2   Steve Davis (Umpire)           $45,000             $3,000       $1000

3   Tony Hill (Umpire)         $30,000             $3,000       $850

4   Ian Gould (Umpire)         $45,000             $3,000       $1000

5   Rod Tucker (Umpire)        $45,000             $3,000       $1000

6   Marais Erasmus (Umpire)        $35,000             $3,000       $850

7   Kumar Dharmasena (Umpire)      $30,000             $3,000       $850